# Shopware 6 API: How to get the URL of a product

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

What's the way to go in order to get the URL of a single product detail page using the Shopware 6 Store API?

I'm fetching a list of products in a single category by using the `/store-api/product-listing/{categoryId}` API endpoint. This works fine except I cannot find any hint for the product (detail page) URL in the response. Even fetching a single product via the `/store-api/product/{productId}` does not contain that information.

The field `seoUrls` in the API response, which sounds like it might contain URLs, is `NULL` for all products.
Thanks for any hints in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The operation of fetching SEO URLs for e.g. a list of products can be quite costly, especially for stores with a lot of products. For that reason, Shopware doesn't populate that field by default.

Secondly - not every application that relies on Shopware 6's Store API also uses its SEO implementation - some applications implement custom routes, so it would be useless to populate it anyway.

The answer:

Add the `sw-include-seo-urls: 1` header to any of your requests that contain SEO URLs and Shopware will try to resolve the correct SEO URL for every entity in the response:

Request:

```json
// POST /product-listing/bda4b60e...
// sw-include-seo-urls: 1


{
    "includes": {
        "product_listing": ["elements"],
        "product": ["name", "seoUrls"],
        "seo_url": ["seoPathInfo"]
    },
    "limit": 3
}
```

Response:

```json
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "name": "ADELAIDE 1",
            "seoUrls": [
                {
                    "seoPathInfo": "ADELAIDE-1\/SW10156",
                    "apiAlias": "seo_url"
                }
            ],
            "apiAlias": "product"
        },
        {
            "name": "BAREFOOT BROTZEITBRETTL",
            "seoUrls": [
                {
                    "seoPathInfo": "BAREFOOT-BROTZEITBRETTL\/SW10412",
                    "apiAlias": "seo_url"
                }
            ],
            "apiAlias": "product"
        },
        {
            "name": "BASE",
            "seoUrls": [
                {
                    "seoPathInfo": "BASE\/SW10185",
                    "apiAlias": "seo_url"
                }
            ],
            "apiAlias": "product"
        }
    ],
    "apiAlias": "product_listing"
}
```

This works for categories and products.

Also see the [Store API FAQ Section](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/ZG9jOjExMjg5MDA2-faq).

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much! After adding the sw-include-seo-urls header to the request, the URLs are now populated in the response. Great.